# Prim's MST algorithm in O(|V|^2)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic, implementation, prims-algorithm

Time complexity of **Prim's MST algorithm** is `O(|V|^2)` if you use adjacency matrix representation.

I am trying to implement Prim's algorithm using adjacency matrix. I am using [**this**](http://lcm.csa.iisc.ernet.in/dsa/node183.html)
as a reference.

```
V = {1,2...,n}
U = {1}
T = NULL
while V != U:

     /* 
         Now this implementation means that 
         I find lowest cost edge in O(n).
         How do I do that using adjacency list? 
     */

     let (u, v) be the lowest cost edge 
                such that u is in U and v is in V - U;

     T = T + {(u,v)}
     U = U + {v}
```

**EDIT:**

1. I understand Prim's algorithm very well.
2. I know how to implement it efficiently using heaps and priority queues.
3. I also know about better algorithms.
4. I want to use adjacency matrix representation of graph and get O(|V|^2) implementation.

**I WANT THE INEFFICIENT IMPLEMENTATION**

Comment: Here is V^2 implementation towards the end of page http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Algorithms/MyAlgorithms/GraphAlgor/primAlgor.htm

Answer (score 6):

Finding the lowest cost edge (*u*,*v*), such that *u* is in U and *v* is in V-U, is done with a *priority queue*. More precisely, the priority queue contains each node *v* from V-U together with the lowest cost edge from *v* into the current tree U. In other words, the queue contains exactly |V-U| elements.

After adding a new node *u* to U, you have to update the priority queue by checking whether the neighboring nodes of *u* can now be reached by an edge of lower cost than previously.

The **choice of priority queue** determines the time complexity. You will get O(|V|^2) by implementing the priority queue as a simply array `cheapest_edges[1..|V|]`. That's because finding minimum in this queue takes O(|V|) time, and you repeat that |V| times.

In pseudo-code:

```
V = {2...,n}
U = {1}
T = NULL
P = array, for each v set P[v] = (1,v)

while V != U

    (u,v) = P[v] with v such that  length P[v]  is minimal

    T = T + {(u,v)}
    U = U + {v}

    for each w adjacent to v
        if length (v,w) < length P[w] then
            P[w] = (v,w)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do it like in [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), by selecting the node that is connected to your current partial tree with the minimum cost edge (that doesn't generate a cycle). I think [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm) explains Prim better than that pseudocode you have. Give it a look and let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Problem is not understanding algorithm. I understand it quite well. 
Problem is not efficient implementation. There are many using priority queues. Problem is how do I implement it with exactly O(|V|^2) complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the edges by the cost and then iterate the edges in the order of the cost, and if that edge joins two distinct subgraphs use that edge.

I have a implementation [here](http://infoarena.ro/job_detail/273777?action=view-source). It reads the number of verticles (N), the number of edges (M) and the edges in order (A, B, Cost) and then outputs the edges. This is the Kruskal algorithm.

A implementation of the Prim's algorithm with a heap, using the same input can be found [here](http://infoarena.ro/job_detail/234741?action=view-source).